# Push rejected, failed to compile python app error while trying to deploy flask app

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I'm getting a rejected error when trying to deploy a Flask app to Heroku.

This is the build log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnVwp.png

My requirements.txt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CgsE.png

Procfile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDQIv.png

Can someone provide a solution?

Comment: please don't send image, just copy-paste content as text here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.